# How to display a coordinate on a graph every 0.001s

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have (x,y) coordinates which are stored in nested lists, they correspond to times going up in 0.001s. I would like to display these points in a bitmap in real time so that it draws the path of an object. I have tried this but it requires me to click a button hundreds of times and it redraws all of the points every time. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you try timer ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I have a timer but the problem is that it doesn't refresh the bitmap so it just plots it once. I don't know how to refresh it.

Comment: Are you using System.Drawing? I guess then you could say Invalidate() to re-render

Comment: I think that has fixed it, you're a beautiful human being.

Comment: Please post code to show what you already got. We can take off from there. Outside that: 0.001s - that's 1/1000s . You know your eyes will stop noticing a small leap way earlier?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!